# Having count with case when in a temporary table in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to make a query to return a table based on a having count condition, if the row count is > 2, then it should return me only the max value of a field and make a union with another table. If it's equal to 1, then just pull everything of the table, it would look something a little like this, I don't know the correct syntax for snowflake tho:

```
WITH TEMP_SHIPMENTS AS (
    SELECT 
      ORDERNUMBER,
      POSITIONNUMBER,
      ITEMCODE,
      ITEMDESCRIPTION,
      SHIPMENTNUMBER,
      LOAD,
      QUANTITY,
      SERIALNUMBER,
      CUSTOMERNAME,
      SHIPTOADDRESS,
      MAX(CUSTOMERORDER),
      CUSTOMERLINE,
      DELIVERYDATE
    FROM 
        T_SHIPMENTS


    GROUP BY
        ORDERNUMBER,
      POSITIONNUMBER,
      ITEMCODE,
      ITEMDESCRIPTION,
      SHIPMENTNUMBER,
      LOAD,
      QUANTITY,
      SERIALNUMBER,
      CUSTOMERNAME,
      SHIPTOADDRESS,
      CUSTOMERORDER,
      CUSTOMERLINE,
      DELIVERYDATE
)
CASE WHEN HAVING COUNT FROM TEMP_SHIPMENTS.CUSTOMERORDER >2
THEN
SELECT ORDERNUMBER,
      POSITIONNUMBER,
      ITEMCODE,
      ITEMDESCRIPTION,
      SHIPMENTNUMBER,
      LOAD,
      QUANTITY,
      SERIALNUMBER,
      CUSTOMERNAME,
      SHIPTOADDRESS,
      CUSTOMERORDER,
      CUSTOMERLINE,
      MAX(DELIVERYDATE) 
FROM TEMP_SHIPMENTS;
```

Any ideas on how I could achieve it?

```
 SELECT 
      ORDERNUMBER,
      POSITIONNUMBER,
      ITEMCODE,
      ITEMDESCRIPTION,
      SHIPMENTNUMBER,
      LOAD,
      QUANTITY,
      SERIALNUMBER,
      CUSTOMERNAME,
      SHIPTOADDRESS,
      CUSTOMERORDER,
      CUSTOMERLINE,
      DELIVERYDATE
    FROM 
        T_SHIPMENTS
    WHERE SerialNumber = '012501003449'   ;
```

[Result table from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKYH0.png)
I left the result in here, and as you can see I have the same serialNumber with two records, which is okay but I only need one. And that would be the one that has either the greatest datetime or the greatest customerorder number. I tried by querying with the max value but achieved nothing on either of these fields, I still get two records instead of just one with the maximum value

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I just added an edit for it and an image, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to return the row of the `MAX(CUSTOMERORDER)`, I would try:

```
WITH TEMP_SHIPMENTS AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY SERIALNUMBER ORDER BY CUSTOMERORDER desc) row_num,
      ORDERNUMBER,
      POSITIONNUMBER,
      ITEMCODE,
      ITEMDESCRIPTION,
      SHIPMENTNUMBER,
      LOAD,
      QUANTITY,
      SERIALNUMBER,
      CUSTOMERNAME,
      SHIPTOADDRESS,
      CUSTOMERORDER,
      CUSTOMERLINE,
      DELIVERYDATE
    FROM 
        T_SHIPMENTS
)

SELECT *
FROM TEMP_SHIPMENTS
WHERE row_num = 1
```

It's unclear by your question if this should be the max `ordernumber` over the entire table or max `ordernumber` for a group - based on the image you attached it sounds like you want the max `ordernumber` for each `serialnumber`, so that is what I partitioned over. However, you can make that partition be `itemdescription` or `customername` if you'd like the max `ordernumber` of an item or customer, respectively.

Comment: This actually works pretty good, I wasn't aware of the partition by clause in snowflake. And yes, it was the max order number for each serialnumber. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't really do conditional unions in pure SQL in any database, nor use HAVING clause for anything else than grouping results refinement.